# React native, action not dispatching

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to dispatch an action to update my state, I am using a `picker` in my component, I don't get any errors but state doesn't update. Any ideas?

```
onChange = e => {
    setSelectedView(e);
};

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
                source={require("../img/logoGreen.png")}
                style={{ width: 150, height: 100 }}
            />
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
                <Text>Please select a year</Text>
                <Picker selectedValue={0} onValueChange={onChange}>
                    {studentYears.map((year, i) => {
                        return (
                            <Picker.Item
                                key={year.id}
                                label={year.title}
                                value={year.value}
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </Picker>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        selectedView: state.selectedView
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        setSelectedView: e => dispatch(setSelectedView(e))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

Reducer:

```
export function setSelectedView(state = 0, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_SELECTED_VIEW":
            return action.setSelectedView;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Action:

```
export const setSelectedView = int => ({
    type: "SET_SELECTED_VIEW",
    selectedView: int
});
```

Store:

```
import {
    eventsFetchData,
    eventsHasErrored,
    eventsIsLoading,
    eventsFetchDataSuccess,
    setSelectedView
} from "../actions/events";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const initialState = {
    eventsHasErrored: false,
    eventsIsLoading: true,
    events: [],
    setSelectedView: { selectedView: 0 }
};

const reduxLogger = createLogger();

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk, reduxLogger)
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in your reducer

```
export function setSelectedView(state = 0, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "SET_SELECTED_VIEW":
            return action.selectedView;//instead of action.setSelectedView;

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```